# Getting error on parsing a DateTime that sounds valid

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have written this:

```vb
Dim dtttm As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(value, 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

and the value that gets passed in is

```vb
17/07/30 12:00:00 AM
```

But I get the error:

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: You need to use `ParseExact` and pass in the exact format if you're going to deal with unusual formats, like where the year comes first:: `DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yy/MM/dd h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: If your culture is US, it's expecting the month first, so it won't like 17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `InvariantCulture` uses `MM/dd/yy` date format.  Your input appears to be in `dd/MM/yy` format (17 July 1930), or it might be in `yy/MM/dd` format (30 July 2017).  I can't tell.

You should use `ParseExact` instead, using the format that matches your input:

```vb
Dim dtttm As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt" 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Ideally, avoid ambiguous data.  Use `yyyy-MM-dd` format whenever possible.
https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: ...why the "invariant" is the US format is something I've never been able to figure out...

Comment: Perhaps because Microsoft is a US company?